# Devise Combinatorics Naming Convention

Tags: math, probability, combinatorics

I stumbled upon a problem that I'm looking for an smart solution to. It's basically a combinatorics question.

I have five objects of which I need to select two, I can select the same one twice and it does not matter in which order I select them. This gives me ( 5 + 2 - 1 choose 2) = 15 possible combinations. I now want to reduce each combination (ie (1,1) or (2, 5)) to a number between 1 and 15. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quasi lexicographic ordering. Assign each selection its position in the lexicographic ordering, with the second component not smaller than the first.

```
(i,j) -> (15 - (7-i)*(6-i)/2) + (j - i) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought there probably was a name for it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a combination (i, j)

Without losing generality, say i <= j

```
((7-i)+5)*(i-1)/2 + (j-i+1)
```

You'll have

(1, 1)->1  (2, 2)->6  (3, 3)->10  (4, 4)->13  (5, 5)->15

(1, 2)->2  (2, 3)->7  (3, 4)->11  (4, 5)->14

(1, 3)->3  (2, 4)->8  (3, 5)->12

(1, 4)->4  (2, 5)->9

(1, 5)->5

Basically you'll first have the number of combinations before column i, then plus (j-i+1) as the row number

Comment: You can't assume `i < j`; the OP can select the same term twice.  As well, this gives numbers beyond 15, e.g. `(i,j) = 4,5` gives 17, if my arithmetic is right.

Comment: @DSM but the OP said the order doesn't matter

Comment: That order doesn't matter means that you can choose `i <= j`, not `i < j`, because the OP could select the same term twice (e.g. (4,4)).  I still can't match your numbers, though.

Comment: @DSM In OP's question, (3,4) and (4,3) are the same combination. In my formula, (i,j) and (j,i) denote the same thing, and I always use j to denote the larger number.

Comment: Let me try one last time: if i = 4, and j = 4, it is not true that `i <  j`, because 4 = 4, not 4 < 4.  You mean `i <= j`, not `i < j`.  Second: take your formula, ((i+1)+5)*(i-1)/2 + (j-i+1).  Put in i=4, j=5.  You get 17, not 14.

Comment: @DSM, oh.. i misunderstood you, sorry, my math is even worse than I thought.. fixed.. I guess essentially I'm doing the same thing as Daniel..